# Make QuickTime player ignore mouse gestures and touches

Tags: macos, quicktime, mouse

I like my Magic Mouse, but I often touch it "incorrectly" while watching a movie in QuickTime Player, and QTP then moves the video position forward or backwards or makes a pause or ... . It can be annoying :-(

I'd like to make my QuickTime Player ignore mouse gestures and touches. Is it possible?

Comment: when you touch it incorrectly, does it protest?

Comment: @cala depends on the movie he's watching :-°

Answer (score 1):

You can try [**BetterTouchTool**](http://boastr.net/) that will give you **much** more control.

There is a setting that will allow you to add per-application rules:

[image: better touch tool settings bettertouchtool]

Comment: I tried to add some gestures for QTPlayer and send random key or take "No Action". It didn't help :-( QTP still does execute its actions.

Answer (score 1):

[image: BetterTouchTool]

As Loïc Wolff says BetterTouchTool is a way to disable this horizontal scrolling. I was searching about the same problem and found the solution in this program (BetterTouchTool)